# Any way to change JTable component default behavior

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings

is there any way to change default shortcuts used by JTable? For instance I would like to change Home and End keys, so they would move to first/last row instead of first/last column.

Any way to do this? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use inputmap with the following strings **"selectLastRow"** and **"selecFirstRow"**

Like this:

```
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_HOME, 0), "selectFirstRow");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ctrl+HOME` and `Ctrl+END` to move to the first/last row. You should try not to change this behaviour because this is what users are used to.