# Custom navigation over rows of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to go to last row in JTable when we press Up key at first row and also how to go to first row when we press Down key at last row? Like Enter key does when we press Enter key at last row it will go to the first row.

I already done this coding but it just show data to text field:

```
private void jtKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ||evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        int row=jt.getSelectedRow();
        String TableClick=(jt.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
        try{
            String sql="select Product,Roo,TotalStock from pro where                  
            Product='"+TableClick+ "'";
            PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement)     
            conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
            if(res.next()){
                String add1=res.getString("Product");
                proo.setText(add1);
                // String add2=res.getString("Id");
                //idd.setText(add2);
                String add3=res.getString("Roo");
                rooo.setText(add3);
                String add4=res.getString("TotalStock");
                stkk.setText(add4);
                abc=res.getString("TotalStock");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        } //catch
    } // if
}
```

Comment: When posting code, _please_ format it properly. I suppose you're using an IDE that can do it in a moment so those who will want to answer your question won't have to dig their way through the formatting. I formatted the code for you, next time please format it youself. Also, questions should refrain from anything like "please help" and "thanks in advance". Questions should be as condensed as possible so they are easier to read and answer.

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167712/any-way-to-change-jtable-component-default-behavior. I re-opened this question because I interpret this question to mean the OP wants to change the functionality of the up/down keys to wrap to the bottom/top, which is not addressed in the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two custom Actions:

1. one Action to wrap from the first row to the bottom and
2. another Action to wrap from the bottom to the top.

The easiest way to do this is to take advantage of existing Actions defined in JTable. The UP keys move up one line at a time and the Down key moves down one line at a time. You can also use CTRL+HOME to go to the top line and CTRL_END to go to the last line.

So I would suggest to start with the UP Action and modify it to implement the CTRL+END Action. The easiest way to do this is to take advantage of the concept of [Wrapping Actions](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/wrapping-actions/). This class is a wrapper class for an existing Action and allows you to add custom code to enhance the Action.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UpAction extends WrappedAction implements ActionListener
{
    private JTable table;
    private Action endAction;

    /*
     *  Specify the component and KeyStroke for the Action we want to wrap
     */
    public UpAction(JTable table, KeyStroke keyStroke)
    {
        super(table, keyStroke);
        this.table = table;
        endAction = table.getActionMap().get("selectLastRow");
    }

    /*
     *  Provide the custom behaviour of the Action
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (table.getSelectedRow() == 0)
            endAction.actionPerformed( e );
        else
            invokeOriginalAction( e );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(7, 5);
        new UpAction(table, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(table) );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You would need to create a similar Action for the DOWN functionality. Note the action string name for selecting the first row is: `selectFirstRow`. Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of all the Actions used by a given component.